# how to hide/remove icon menu items in actionbar when moving bottomnavigation kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-actionbar, bottomnavigationview

in actionbar home fragment bottomnavigation

[image]

in action bar favorite fragment bottomnavigation

[image]

how to hide or remove actionbar icon when moving to favorite fragment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to make your `FavoriteFragment` options menu aware and then in `onCreateOptionsMenu`, simply clear the `menu`. this can be done by updating `FavoriteFragment` with following changes

In `onCreateView`, call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` to receive options menu related callbacks in `Fragment`

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Allows your fragment to receive options menu related callbacks (onCreateOptionsMenu etc)
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    ...
}
```

now override `onCreateOptionsMenu` and clear the already populated `menu` as

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    menu.clear()
}
```